# Why I am not able to use await keyword before async method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, stream

I have written the below code-snippet in `Main` method. I'm not able to use await keyword before `WriteAsync()`.

**snippet-1:**

```
while (fileLength < 100)
            {
                i = i + 1;
                sampleText = String.Format("Line {0} of {1} \n", i, lineCount);
                data = encoding.GetBytes(sampleText);
                fileStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
                fileLength = fileLength + data.Length;
                Console.WriteLine("Length of file written: " + fileLength);
            }
 fileStream.Close();
```

**snippet-2:**

```
while (fileStream1.Position == fileLength)
            {
                 fileStream1.ReadAsync(data, 0, 100);
            }
```

The connection is closed in snippet-1 after the execution of while loop and snippet-2 is working fine.

**while executing it I have got the following queries:**

1. Is it mandatory to  use await operator before `WriteAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`?
2. Can we use `ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` without any await operator?
3. Can we use `Thread.Sleep` in place of await operator?

I have little experience in C# and multi-threading. Can any one help me in getting understand on the above queries?

Comment: case you are using .net core 3 or later you can change the main method to work with async operations, just change the void with async Task

Comment: you can use async void too for older versions

Comment: 1. No, but then it won't do what you want, it won't wait. 2. Yes, but it won't do what you want 3. No, it does something different. In short: yes, no, no, respectively. Side points: you should use a proper `using` block, and in modern versions of C# you can do `await using` which call `DisposeAsync`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can  create an  `wrap` method and `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` inside `Main` eg.

```
public void Main()
{
   MainWrap().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
private async Task MainWrap()
{
    await SomeStuff();
}
```

2. you can simply use `public async Task Main()`  as the entrypoint (it's almost the same as first solution)

---

and for the reason,  you simply think `async` `await` it a syntactic sugar for `SoThingsWithoutWait(Func<objct> onDoneCallback)`,  the `async` keyword is for mark the`context` will generate those callback (they are actully a state machine that for create a new `Task` base on your `await` chain )  and the `await` keyword is an mark for create an "state" inside the state machine.
so without the async keyword and an "awaitable type" ,  you can not genreate the state machine code.